# How to parse json response data from url using php

Tags: php, json, curl

I am trying to parse the JSON response from PHP. How can i get values from JSON response by keys.Thanks in advance.

```
$ch=curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,'https://www.instamojo.com/api/1.1/payment-requests/');
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,array('X-Api-Key: SomeKEY','X-Auth-Token: SomeToken'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER,0);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POST,1);
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,http_build_query($req_data,'','&'));
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,130);
$json= curl_exec($ch);
if($err=curl_error($ch)) {
  var_dump($err);
 }
 var_dump($json);
 $jsonArray= json_decode($json,true);
```

Comment: If your code is correct you should have a normal array in `$jsonArray`.

Comment: string(840) "{ "payment_request": { "id": "26afecc7796a402fbe12293745e49b99", "phone": "+918983501918", "email": "test@wifi-soft.com", "buyer_name": "ganesh more", "amount": "10", "purpose": "Wifi Service", "email_status": null, "shorturl": null, "longurl":"https://www.instamojo.com/@shaikh1280/26afecc7796a402fbe12293745e49b99", "redirect_url":"http://172.31.254.38/wifilan/api/success.php", "webhook": "http://172.31.254.38/wifilan/api/postintamojo.php", "created_at": "2016-03-18T14:59:16.772Z", "modified_at": "2016-03-18T14:59:16.772Z", "allow_repeated_payments": true }, "success": true } "

Comment: this is my response array how can i parse longurl from this array using PHP. Thanks

Comment: That's not an array, that's a json string. Is that an echo of $json or $jsonArray?

Comment: It's an  var_dump($json) i am getting above response array containing array i want to parse longurl value from this dynamically.

Comment: Try to dump `$jsonArray`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$jsonArray['payment_request']['longurl']
```

should have the long url value you are looking for.

Hope it helps.